# Printing the fibonacci sequence in reverse using arrays - Java

Tags: java, fibonacci

Used to print the fibonacci in normal order, but can't figure out how to reverse it, from 4181 to 0.

```
    int[] numbers = new int[20];

    numbers[0] = 0;
    numbers[1] = 1;


    System.out.println("Fibonacci sequence:");
    System.out.println( numbers[0] );
    System.out.println( numbers[1] );


    for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++) {


        numbers[i] = numbers[i-2] + numbers[i-1];
        System.out.println( numbers[i] );
        for (int j = 19; j >= 0; j++) {
            numbers[j] = numbers[j-2] + numbers[j-1];
        System.out.println( numbers[j] );
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Put your results into an array. Reverse iterate the array to print.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is defined with `a0 = a1 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Second loop has incorrect increment part - instead of `j++` there should be `j--`. What it says now is "start with number 19. Continue while the number is bigger or equal to 0.

Every iteration **INCREASE** the number by 1".

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to create the Fibonacci sequence recursively (like you did) first, and then reverse it:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Another (mathematically more elegant) solution would be using the explicit formula to calculate each member of the Fibonacci sequence by its index, starting from `n = 20` and work your way down to `n = 1`:

```
p = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
q = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2
F(n) = ((p ^ n) - (q ^ n)) / sqrt(5)
```

Comment: Speaking of recursion: ```void fibo(int pp,int p,int n){   System.out.println(pp+p);if(n>0)fibo(p,pp+p,n-1);}``` vs. ```void rfibo(int pp,int p,int n){if(n>0)rfibo(p,pp+p,n-1);System.out.println(pp+p);}```, both started with (0,1,17)